# python- cannot run a simple pro

Tags: python

hi im a beginner of python and linux. im using visual studio code and python 3.5.2
im trying to run something very simple unsuccess . tnx
so this is my code:

```
import random

def randomNumber():
    n=random.randint(1,100)
    print (n)
    checkMatch(n)


def checkMatch(compNum):
    playerNum= int(input("choose num between 1 to 100: "))
    if playerNum==compNum:
        print ("congratulation you won!")
    elif playerNum<compNum:
        print ("sorry but the num you choose is smaller then the right answer")
    else:
        print("sorry but the num you choose is bigger then the right answer")
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Describe the expected behavior and what actually happens, along with any error messages including the full traceback.

Comment: So what's the problem? What's the expected result? Please see [mcve].

Comment: your function works fine, have you added the line `randomNumber()` at the end (not as part of any `def`)? You have only defined functions here, not called them.

Comment: just place in your code the actual call `randomNumber()` at the end to run it, as the interpreter does not know what to run unless you call it.

Comment: tnx for helping . my explanation wasnt enought, i do call the func so it is working .. but when it get to the ifs part nothing happen

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: version 2.7.12 ..

Answer (score 1):

The code presented has nothing which would be expected to run, as such. You define two functions, but they are never called and so nothing happens.

Try adding `randomNumber()` at the end, I think that then the program will work as intended.

Comment: hey sorry for my bad explanation im new on stack over flow too... so it is worhing .. but when it get to the ifs part nothing happen

Comment: So, you are prompted for the input but you aren't seeing output?

Comment: yea its like when it get to the input line its asking a num ,im doing it and push enter and then nothing happend..im mean it didnt get next to the ifs lines.  i tried to delete the input line .. and i put there a number and now its working..   i dont see why it makes change ..

Comment: @GalShimoni have you tried separating out the call into input onto a separate line, and assigning it to a variable?

Comment: i tried this.. again nothing happens after entering a chosen number:

playerNum= input("choose num between 1 to 100")###################

playerNum2= int(playerNum,base=0)

Comment: What happens if you print the variable?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the function to run. Add `randomNumber()` to the end of your program. Were you getting an error with your `if` statements? Please edit your post if you were. It is working fine for me.